# parse error in pattern:?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, functional-programming

I am newbie to Haskell and trying to build simple `billing system for a Fastfood stall`.and I defined `linkItem function`(in the last part of the code), which operates over an entire list, in terms of the
local function `linkBill`, which  operates on just one element. `linkBill` looks for
a matching code, returns the relevant bill type, or  causes a run-time error
if there is no such code entry in `itemDb`.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char

type Name = String
type Code = Int
type Price = Float
type ToatalQtity = Int

type Db = [(Code,Name,Price,ToatalQtity)]

itemDb :: Db
itemDb = [(1234,"Chicken Lollypop",250.00,50),
          (2222,"Chili Mushroom",150.00,50),
          (1111,"Paneer Pakora",100.00,100),
          (4719,"Fish Fingers",121.00,100),
          (1235,("Tandoori Chicken",200.00,50))]

type ItemCode = [Code]
type BillType = [(Name,Price)]

till :: ItemCode
till = [1234,2222,1111,4719,1235]

lookupBy :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe b
lookupBy f [] = Nothing
lookupBy f (x:xs) = case f x of
                  Nothing -> lookupBy f xs
                  r       -> r

linkItem :: ItemCode -> BillType
linkItem = map linkBill 
         where linkBill code' = case lookupBy (matchingCode code') itemDb of 
                                Just item -> item 
                                Nothing -> Error "**WRONG CODE, NO ITEMFOUND**"
                                matchingCode (code') (code,name,price,_) 
                                                          | (code' == code) = Just (name,price)
                                                          | otherwise = Nothing
```

and whenever I compiling it ,it's showing an error as below:

```
billing.hs:48:34: error: Parse error in pattern: matchingCode
   |
48 |       matchingCode (code') (code,name,price)     
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                | (code' == code) = Just (name,price)
   Failed, 0 modules loaded
```

I think am doing something wrong here at `matchingCode` function declaration I dont know what ? what can I doto get rid of these kinds of Errors?

Comment: outdent the definition of `matchingCode` so it is at the same level as the definition of `linkBill`

Comment: you mean.I should not put both of them in same line ?  @pat... I tried that too in that case its showing like  `parse error on input`..what should i do

Answer (score 2):

Indent the code for the function definitions inside the `where` are at the same level of indent:

```
linkItem :: ItemCode -> BillType
linkItem = map linkBill where
  linkBill code' = case lookupBy (matchingCode code') itemDb of 
    Just item -> item 
    Nothing   -> error "**WRONG CODE, NO ITEMFOUND**"
  matchingCode code' (code, name, price, _) | code' == code = Just (name, price)
                                            | otherwise     = Nothing
```

You also want `error` instead of `Error` (assuming you *really* want to use `error` for error handling).